# nginx allow ssl on ec2 using aws load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, amazon-ec2

I've installed nginx on an ec2 to test how it would perform against another ec2 without nginx.

It works just fine on port 80, but I'm having trouble allowing ssl. when I go to my domain using https, it just times out.

I have already installed the ssl on the aws load balancer. How do fix this issue?

Here is the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file:

```
http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl default_server;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/agori.access.log  main;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/agori.error.log;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ec2-user/src/project.sock;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are terminating SSL at the ELB, you should not have any SSL related settings in your nginx config.  Your ELB needs to forward to port 80 of your instance from it's port 443 SSL listener

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. Please post as answer to get credit.